# Can't find syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

Could someone please help me find the syntax error, its supposed to by occurring on line 78. At this point I am convinced there isn

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

$LOAD_PATH.unshift "lib"
require 'wordnet'
require 'pp'


print_synsets = false



lex = WordNet::Lexicon.new

puts "Hello! I'm Complainbot. To stop talking to enter \'cya\'. What would you like to complain about today?\n\n"
user_response = gets.chomp

while not user_response.include? "cya" do
    puts

    if is_command?(user_response)
        handle_commands(user_response)
    else
        establish_context(user_response)
    end

    puts

    user_response = gets.chomp
end



def establish_context(sentence)
    nouns = get_nouns(sentence)
    puts nouns
end


def get_nouns(sentence)
    words = sentence.strip.split(' ')
    nouns_in_sentence = []

    words.each do |word|
        word_synsets = lex.lookup_synsets(word)

        if print_synsets do PP.pp(word_synsets) end

        word_synsets.each do |synset|
            nouns = synset.nouns
            if not nouns.empty?
                nouns_in_sentence.append(nouns.first)
                break
            end
        end
    end
    return nouns_in_sentence
end


def is_command?(sentence)
    words = sentence.strip.split(' ')

    if words.first[0].to_s == '\\' then 
        return true 
    else 
        return false
    end 
end


def handle_commands(commands)
    if commands.include? 'PRINT_SYNSETS'
        print_synsets = true
    elsif commands.include? '~PRINT_SYNSETS'
        print_synsets = false
    end
end
```

Comment: Hello, you should indent all your code four spaces so it will be correctly formatted.

Comment: It's recommended to leave the keyword `do` _only_ for blocks.

Comment: For one-liner blocks, use the curly braces instead of `do ... end`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Incorrectly matched blocks will be pretty easy to find if you indent your code using a tool, not by hand. Any decent editor will let you do that. Also, take the time to format your question correctly and use proper grammar. The effort you put in reflects on how much you want to help the site, and effects the effort people put into helping you.

Comment: 2 spaces per indentation level: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#spaces-indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` expressions in Ruby don't require `then`

```
if words.first[0].to_s == '\\'
    return true 
else 
    return false
end
```

UPDATE - 
While the above is true, as @JörgWMittag pointed out, this is not the cause of the problem.  The actual problem lies in `if print_synsets do PP.pp(word_synsets) end`.  As he stated, the use of `then` instead of `do` would be the fix here.

Comment: How the heck did this get accepted? It is technically not wrong, `if` expressions (that part *is* wrong, `if` is an expression in Ruby, not a statement) don't *require* `then`, you can use `;` or a newline instead, but it doesn't *hurt* either, and it is definitely *not* the cause of this syntax error. Quite the opposite, actually, the error is caused by using `do` with `if` a couple of lines further up, and the correct fix is precisely to use `then` instead of `do`.

Comment: Yep, I think you're right @JörgWMittag.  Thanks for your correction!